# Rails3 and Arel to select using IN and subselect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I have a table called translations. (And a correspoding ActiveRecord class).
This table contains the following fields
id, key and value

I would like to select all translations where the key matches a given query + all the translations that don't match the query, but share the key with a translation which does matches the query.

The resulting SQL could look something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TRANSLATIONS where key in
    (select key from Translations where value like '%some search%')
```

I've tried a few things, but I can't seem to figure it out.
Any ideas on how to express this in Arel?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
t = Table(:translations)
c = t.where(t[:value].matches('%some search%')).project(:key)
t.where(t[:key].in(c))
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer.

This piece of code does generate a sql statement that looks like it should do the thing, however mysql complains with error in syntax.

It renders this: 
SELECT `translations`.* FROM `translations` WHERE (`translations`.`key` IN 
(SELECT key FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`value` LIKE '%value1%'))

While it should render:
SELECT `translations`.* FROM `translations` WHERE (`translations`.`key` IN 
(SELECT `translations`.`key` FROM `translations` WHERE `translations`.`value` LIKE '%value1%'))

Is there any way of controlling this?

Comment: Use project(:'translations.key')

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @valodzka, but add "t[....]" around the :key symbol

```
t = Table(:translations)
c = t.where(t[:value].matches('%some search%')).project(t[:key])
t.where(t[:key].in(c))
```